# Suggest changing "share" to "permalink" on answers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

The "share" link under each answer doesn't adequately communicate to users that this is the permalink URL. I suggest changing "share" to "permalink" for the answer links only.

The "Share" link under the actual question seems to clearly communicate that functionality and should remain the same.

Comment: I think it's not technically a permalink, since the URL includes your user ID so they can track how many people click your link. There are a few badges for sharing links visited by X number of unique viewers etc.

Comment: Just thought I'd throw it out there: if you hover over share in the question/answer it says "short permalink to this question" or "short permalink to this answer"

Comment: @AdrianMacneil It is a permalink for all intents and purposes. The user id at the end is actually optional and only used for tracking like you described - you can omit it from any URL and it'll still work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It used to just say "link" on both questions and answers, but that was changed once we rolled out sharing buttons that appear on that same pop-up with the link.

Since you can share answers as well (and you should, if/when you find a really good one :)), I think changing the link text would only be more confusing.

Comment: Can we change both links to "permalink/share"?

Comment: @MediaGirl Then it'd be too verbose for relatively little benefit: as Natetronn mentioned in a comment, the tooltip over "share" explains that it provides a permalink to the post.

Comment: As a side note, if we were to make any changes here, they would apply to the entire network which makes me hesitate further. We do our best to not special-case individual sites to keep the user experience, for better or for worse, consistent across all our sites.

Comment: Understood. I thought these were things we had a chance to change which is why I posted.

Comment: @MediaGirl No worries. Not all of our changes come from the bigger and established sites, so it never hurts to ask. :)

Comment: For us, the change would make it more clear that that link is a permalink. We use that language in our CMS.